# Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::component()/

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, components, laravel-blade

I have tried to create a Blade component in laravel 5.6. I have added this code segment `Blade::component('front.components.filter','filter');` in `AppServiceProvider.php` and add this in my blade file 
`@filter @endfilter`
when I try to run the program I have got this error
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler::component()/`
How can I fix this?

Comment: The file `/resources/views/front/components/filter.blade.php` exists?

Comment: @DimitriMostrey yes

Comment: In the AppServiceProvider do you `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;`? If autoimported (by PHPStorm f.ex.), the wrong Blade could have been selected. This happens sometimes, especially in combination withe the `ide-helper` package. You need the facade.

Comment: @DimitriMostrey yes i have imported this `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade;`

Comment: If, just in case `php artisan config:clear` doesn't solve this I have no idea what's going on. Unless you have misconfigured the use of slots itself, which is probably not the case https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#components-and-slots Personally I'm not a fan of slots because it blurs the HTML readability. Of course, there is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: it's showing the same error. Anyway thanks for your support